# Oracle cannot modify column length

Tags: sql, oracle, alter

I need to alter a column `wrong_ban` in my table `rejected_pih`. Current datatype of this column is `number(9)`, and now I need to modify it to `number`. Here is the code I used :

```
alter table
   rejected_pih
modify
(
   WRONG_BAN number
);
```

The problem is the column type is not changed but there is no any error message, even the log said that this table already altered successfully : `table REJECTED_PIH altered.`. But If I rename the table to another name (e.g. Rejected_PIH_2) then the column can be changed. Please help and thank you!

Comment: what makes you think it hasn't worked? i have tried the following and it was successful. What version of oracle are you using?

create table dg_test (var1 number(9));
desc dg_test;
alter table dg_test modify (var1 number);
desc dg_test;

Comment: I checked the table detail after altering and I saw the type not changed. Yes, I also create a table with same detail with my table then tried to alter my new table, and successfully altered. I dropped old rejected_pih table then rename the new one into rejected_pih, but the column automatically changed to number(9) again. Looks weird.

Comment: @KingGoeks, can you post the outputs of your try here, since it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script that demonstrates that your statement works:

```
create table rejected_pih (WRONG_BAN number(9));
select data_type, data_precision from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'REJECTED_PIH';

DATA_TYPE                                        DATA_PRECISION
------------------------------------------------ --------------
NUMBER                                           9

alter table  rejected_pih modify (WRONG_BAN number);
select data_type, data_precision from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'REJECTED_PIH';

DATA_TYPE                                        DATA_PRECISION
------------------------------------------------ --------------
NUMBER
```

If you checks the definition in your IDE allways refresh metadata before (this **could** be the problem).